# helpme with Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment-tab-host

The idea is this .. I have a screen that shows me a list of people .. I select one of them. And I showed this class

```
public class SlideTabFragment extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

It is a (fragment tab) the idea is to show in this fragment two screens (two fragment) one that shows the data of the person and in the other a list of relatives ..
The point is that every time I go to each fragment always enters the OnCreate of the fragment and the idea is to just do it once. Since the first time I make a call to a webservice that full information.
I call the fragment thus

```
Fragment fragment ;
            if(i == 0 )
            {
                 fragment = new FoodFragment2();
            }
            else
            {
                 fragment = new FoodFragment();
            }
            // Crear un FoodFragment con el nombre como argumento

            return fragment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `new FoodFragment2()` and `new FoodFragment()` you're creating two new fragments every time!

Save the fragments that you create into variables, and before creation - check if they already exist, and only of they don't - create them.

Example:

```
public class Play {
    FoodFragment foodFragment;
    FoodFragment2 foodFragment2 ;

    public FoodFragment createFragment(int i) {
        if(i == 0) {
            if (null == foodFragment2) {
                foodFragment2 = new FoodFragment2();                
            }
            fragment = foodFragment2;
        } else {
            if (null == foodFragment) {
                foodFragment = new FoodFragment();                
            }
            fragment = foodFragment2;
        }        
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I turned.
FoodFragment2 foodFragment2 the class; I am thus creating
public class FoodFragment2 extends Fragment 
as you will see in the createFragment method must return a Fragment variable.
but the global variable is of type FoodFragment foodFragment which asks me to be kind fragment. as I can fix this?

Comment: @user2493770 change the signature of your method to return a Fragment instead of returning a FoodFragment. In the example above it would be changing `public FoodFragment createFragment(int i) ` to: `public Fragment createFragment(int i) `

Comment: @alfasin what will happen during a configuration change? Any thoughts, on that

Comment: @Diode if you're using: `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)` it should survive configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it :)